# Tkinter - getting an array of entry values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, tkinter

I have 20 entries in my Tkinter GUI created using for-loop (there might be more of them in the future and I really don't want to have 50 lines of code just for deifining the entries). I need to collect entries values to create a numpy array out of them. As a shot in the dark I have tried this:

```
master = Tk()

R=StringVar()

namR = []
for ii in range(0,20):
    namR.append(Entry(master), textvariable=R[ii])
    namR[ii].grid(row=2+ii, column=3)
```

which obviously does not work (`StringVar instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`), but I think the goal is clear.

Any suggestions to make this work, please?

Comment: you need list of `StringVar`. `R` is not a list so you can't use `[ii]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include your `textvariable` within the `Entry()` call, not after it (`append(Entry(master, textvariable=xyz))` rather than `append(Entry(master), textvariable=xyz)`). `append()` won't know what to do with the second argument. Next, you can create a `list` for the `StringVar` objects and refer to them with something like `Entry(master, stringvariable=svars[ii])`. However, this is only necessary if you want to do things like variable tracing. If you just want to retrieve the text in an entry object, you can do it with `my_entry.get()`.

```
master = Tk()

namR = []
for ii in range(0,20):
    namR.append(Entry(master))
    namR[ii].grid(row=2+ii, column=3)
```

`[e.get() for e in namR]` will then be a `list` of all the entry contents.